# how to ignore files within subdirectories using chokidar

Tags: node.js, regex, glob, chokidar

I have this directory structure

```
├── components
│   ├── quarks
│   │   └── index.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── bosons
│   │   └── index.js
│   │   └── GridLayout.vue
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── atoms
│   │   └── ButtonStyle.vue
│   │   └── InputStyle.vue
│   │   └── index.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── .......
└─────
```

I'd like to ignore the `index.js` within each folder, but I'm not getting it, I've tried it in several ways

```
const path = require('path')
const chokidar = require('chokidar')
const ROOT_PATH = path.resolve('components')

const watcher = chokidar.watch(ROOT_PATH, {
  ignored: ROOT_PATH + '/*/index.js', //does not work
  ignoreInitial: true
})
```

already tried: 
`'./components/**/index.js'`, 
`'./components/*/index.js'`, 
`'components/*/index.js'`, 
`'components/**/index.js'`, 
`'ROOT_PATH + '/**/index.js'`

Anyone have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: @Emma, the two options does not work, but thanks for trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chokidar seems bugged, defective to ignore files on MacOS, that's the impression I have.

So before running my action, I'm checking to see if the file is the same one I want to ignore.

```
chokidar
  .watch('components', { ignoreInitial: true })
  .on('all', (event, filename) => {
    filename !== 'index.js'
    // action here
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on Mac was using `**`:

```
ignored: ['**/node_modules'],
```

So if the other options don't work because of bugs, go for this one:

```
 ignored: ['**/index.js'],
```

Answer (score 0):

The [chokidar documentation](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) specifies that the `ignored` parameter is [anymatch-compatiable](https://github.com/micromatch/anymatch) so this could be completed in many ways.

Here is a regular expression solution...

Any `index.js` file, even in the root folder:

```
{
    ignored: /(^|[\/\\])index\.js$/,
    // ...
}
```

Only `index.js` file in a sub-folder:

```
{
    ignored: /[\/\\]index\.js$/,
    // ...
}
```

Also note in your example you use `signoreInitial` this is not an option, perhaps you meant `ignoreInitial`?

---

Alternatively with callback:

```
{
    ignored: (path) => { return path.endsWith('\\index.js') || path.endsWith('/index.js'); },
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I wrote `ignoreInitial`wrong  in my question, but I already fixed it. 

none of the options you suggested work for me.

Comment: chokidar continues to observe `index.js`

Comment: @YungSilva sounds like you might be running into a bug see [issue #773](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/773). I've added an alternative to use a callback function see updated answer.

Comment: I tried your alternative, but it still does not work for me, chokidar continuing to observe the index.js :(

Comment: @YungSilva try using the callback method but, add some `console.log` statements - see what you are getting as a `path` value.

Comment: @YungSilva also note I've updated my answer to escape the blackslash in `path.endsWith('\\index.js')` you might want to try that update too.

Comment: `console.log` in the `path` options you suggested does not return anything at all. I also tried to use your last suggestion, but chokidar continuing to observe the index.js ..

Comment: chokidar seems to be bugged or does not work well on MacOS.
Maybe you can help me solve the problem that made me try chokidar, I would be very happy if you could help me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926903/differentiate-creation-renaming-and-updating-content-of-files-with-node