# differentiate creation, renaming and updating content of files with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, fs

I need to perform an action when files from a directory are `created`, `renamed`, or `deleted`. But not when content inside a file `changes`.

how can i do this with native node.js?

I tried

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const ROOT_PATH = path.resolve('components')

fs.watch(ROOT_PATH, (eventType, filename) => {
  console.log(eventType)
})
```

according to the documentation, `eventType` should return `rename` for creating, renaming, deleting.

And `change` when the content changes.

but the problem is that sometimes when I change the contents of some file inside the `components` directory, `eventType` returns`rename` when should it be `change`....

so I am not able to differentiate `creation, rename, delete` from`content change`

can someone help me with a native node solution with the `fs` module?

Comment: Consider how are you changing the file, perhaps the editor you are using is renaming a new file into place after saving. Check via the command line that a simple `echo now updated >> existingfile.txt` actually causes the correct events. You can also test if a file has been deleted by seeing if it current exists via `fs.existsSync`. According to [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7420) other people have had the same problem.

Comment: @DeanTaylor, truth! when I test the terminal, it works fine, when I modify the content, I get a response `change`. any tips on how I can solve this problem with my editor? VSCode

Comment: consider treating `fs.watch` as dumb, depending on the number of files keep track of the current state yourself in an array (if too many this might be a memory issue). On a change / watch notification check that file against your current array to see if it's just been created etc.